# Android - New Location / Geofences APIs

Tags: android, gps

I've tried to run Geofences sample and I've got little confunsed regarding to how it works. 
Prior to go on, I've studied the new APIs and wached this video: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc&list=WLRNCZT9Eq_HTG5jIEFxMpdqoXZBNalekx
So I jumped coding it. I thought that this API would manage the GPS position's captures automatically, in order to get my position.
So at this point raises my doubt. I've only got notified within a geofence, if I turnned my google map app on so my device starts capturing my location thru GPS.
So, what should I do to have "my app" forcing GPS use ?

I appreciate your help.
Best Regards,
Marlus

Comment: So if i read this correctly, you want the GPS to give the user's location automatically without the user doing anything?

Comment: Yes, I want the GPS to give the user's location. As I said, I followed this http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html but I only got the GPS position when I turned the google maps. Just to let you know, I drove to a region where there's no wifi signal, so it was supposed to user the GPS.